# Despite no ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission, my app is thought to be using background location, what could be the cause?

Tags: android, geolocation, google-play, android-manifest, android-permissions

My app ([code on GitHub](https://github.com/commons-app/apps-android-commons)) was rejected by Google Play with reason:

> Please remove the background location permission requested and submit an update to your app.

However, my app does **not** declare the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.apps.photos.permission.GOOGLE_PHOTOS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

I first suspected Mapbox, as my app includes these libraries:

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.1.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-localization-v8:0.11.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-scalebar-v9:0.4.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-telemetry:6.1.0'
```

**However** my app checks location only when the app is running fully visible on the screen.
Also, the **merged manifest** shown by Android Studio does not include `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION`:

[image: Merged manifest Android Studio]

It seems that setting `android:minSdkVersion="29"` would circumvent the issue, but I can't do it as I have thousands of important users below that.

I also tried adding a popup disclaiming that the app uses location in the background (*even though it does not*), but that gets rejected too, with this reason:

> It is possible to deliver a similar experience without access to location in the background.

**Question**: What could be making someone think that I use location in the background?

Comment: Have you tried to deny the location permission to the app, and does it work when you do so?

Comment: @AndreiMărcuţ: Thanks! Do you mean in the app's settings? The settings only have the `Location` permission, nothing about background: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOSSj.jpg After I disable this permission the app works normally except on the map activity where it asks again for the permission.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Any news on that? I have ran on the exact same issue in my project.

Answer (score 5):

From the official [Privacy changes in Android 10](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#access_granted_automatically_when_targeting_android_9_or_lower)

**Access granted automatically when targeting Android 9 or lower**

If your app runs on Android 10 or higher but targets Android 9 (API level 28) or lower, the platform applies the following behavior:

- If your app declares a `<uses-permission>` element for either `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`, the system automatically adds a  element for `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` during installation.
- If your app requests either `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`, the system automatically adds ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION to the request.

**Access when device is upgraded to Android 10**

If a user grants your app access to device location – either `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` – then upgrades their device from Android 9 to Android 10, the system automatically updates the set of location-based permissions granted to your app. The set of permissions that your app receives after the upgrade depends on its target SDK version and its defined permissions, as shown in the following table: [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#access_when_device_is_upgraded_to)

In other words, it all depends on your Target platform version.

Comment: `it all depends on your Target platform version`: Thanks! Here are the versions defined in my app, would you know which one they mean by "target"? minSdkVersion:19 targetSdkVersion:30 compileSdkVersion:30. If target means targetSdkVersion then in the table I match row 2 "_Foreground access only_" which means there should theoretically be no problem?

Comment: I think you have to follow this guide:

To declare the foreground service type for a service in your app, set your app's targetSdkVersion or compileSdkVersion to 29 or higher. Learn more about how foreground services can [continue user-initiated actions](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates#continue-user-initiated-action) that require access to location.

Comment: Thanks! I already use targetSdkVersion:30 compileSdkVersion:30. I am also pretty sure I am following the document you linked to when getting location. And on the opposite I am not using any of what is described at https://developer.android.com/training/location/background